# WordPress permalinks with Windows Server IIS6 - without ISAPI access

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

I'm having trouble to export the website to my client hosting . .
I get an index.php in the url all the time, I've research about it, change the permalink custom structure to: /%postname%/

and add this .htaccess in the root of the hosting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

It doesnt change anything, I've read that I need ISAPI rewrite to make it work, problem is, I don't have the access of the Server to do this . . . only access to a part of their hosting dedicated for this website, and the DB SQL by Navicat.

Is there any possiblity to make with work without access to it ? If yes, How is that possible ?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Wait, so are you using Apache or IIS?

Comment: IIS 6. . . . I dont know what to do to get reach off this index.php :s

Answer (score 1):

IIS doesn't use .htaccess, they use web.config (in IIS 7+) or they would use .htaccess (with some IIS specific changes) with ISAPI Rewrite (in IIS 6). If you don't have access to ISAPI, you're not going to be able to rewrite the `index.php` off the URL.